# How to preload or detect when a CDN hosted video is loaded for above the fold in Gatsby?

Tags: video, iframe, gatsby

Looking to implement a 16:9 video under the navigation and above the fold in my *index.js* but I'm trying to figure out how to preload the video before rendering the page. In my research I've read [Working with Video](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/working-with-video/) that shows how to implement with an iframe:

```
import React from "react"
const Video = ({ videoSrcURL, videoTitle, ...props }) => (
  <div className="video">
    <iframe
      src={videoSrcURL}
      title={videoTitle}
      allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
      frameBorder="0"
      webkitallowfullscreen="true"
      mozallowfullscreen="true"
      allowFullScreen
    />
  </div>
)
export default Video
```

It's mentioned for best results to use a CDN and there is a Vimeo plugin [gatsby-source-vimeo-all](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-vimeo-all/):

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from 'gatsby'

const query = graphql`
  {
    vimeo(link: { eq: "https://vimeo.com/315401283/dfd80bf8c1" }) {
      name
      description
      duration
      link
      aspectRatio
      width
      height
      srcset {
        ...GatsbyVimeoSrcSet
      }
      pictures {
        uri
      }
      user {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`

const Video = () => {
  const { vimeo } = useStaticQuery(query)
  return <video src={vimeo.srcset[0].link} controls autoPlay loop />
}

export default Video
```

I'm already eliminating the video for smaller devices with a React component that detects browser size. My thinking is to use *gatsby-browser.js* to implement with accessing the location data `location.pathname` but I'm not finding any docs on how this should be done. When I research for preloading video I've read:

- [Force a full preload HTML5 video with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581801/force-a-full-preload-html5-video-with-javascript)
- [How to preload video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361657/how-to-preload-video)
- [Video preloading:  must have a valid `as` value in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959527/video-preloading-link-rel-preload-must-have-a-valid-as-value-in-chrome)

Gatsby research:

- [Load third party iframe in React after page load, so that the iframe does not affect PageSpeed score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62871284/load-third-party-iframe-in-react-after-page-load-so-that-the-iframe-does-not-af)
- [(Gatsby) Datawrapper iframes aren't displaying before I've refreshed the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70377742/gatsby-datawrapper-iframes-arent-displaying-before-ive-refreshed-the-page)
- [Embedding a video with Gatsby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67907874/embedding-a-video-with-gatsby-iframe)

In Gatsby how should a video be handled for the *index.js* located above the fold or is there a way in Gatsby to detect when the iframe is loaded so I could use a conditional render?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way in Gatsby to detect when the iframe is loaded so I
> could use a conditional render?

Indeed there is, and I think this will be the easiest and most native solution, using the `onLoad` event.

```
<iframe
  src={videoSrcURL}
  title={videoTitle}
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
  frameBorder="0"
  webkitallowfullscreen="true"
  mozallowfullscreen="true"
  allowFullScreen
  onLoad={someOnLoadFunction}
/>
```

In this case, you can use `someOnLoadFunction` to conditional render.

Overall, I'm not sure if this solution is what you are looking for because there's no way to preload (or lazy-load) an iframe without requesting it by the browser. However, depending on your specs, you can try using the `loading` property which [is not fully supported](https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr) but maybe what you are looking for along with the `onLoad` event callback.

```
<iframe
  src={videoSrcURL}
  title={videoTitle}
  allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
  frameBorder="0"
  webkitallowfullscreen="true"
  mozallowfullscreen="true"
  allowFullScreen
  onLoad={someOnLoadFunction}
  loading="lazy"
/>
```